# How to not show minimized windows in GNOMEs activities overview?

Tags: gnome, window, activities-overview

In the overview **every** open Program is shown, but I only want to spread the windows that aren't minimized. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: Show all running applications is by design. There won't be an easy way to change this. You might find an extension at the [extension site](https://extensions.gnome.org/), but I looked at the first 25 pp and didn't find one.

Comment: Too bad, i find it very confusing to see everything i have open ... But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME Shell extension called [Hide minimized by danigm](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2639/hide-minimized/) does this.

I found this on the answer to this question:
[How do I hide minimised windows from Activities overview in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213645/how-do-i-hide-minimised-windows-from-activities-overview-in-gnome-3/1213646#1213646)