# How do I hide minimised windows from Activities overview in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, activities-overview, minimize

In GNOME 3, I can open the *Activities* overview by clicking the 'Activities' button in the top-left corner or by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (usually the the key with the Windows logo). I see previews of all the *open* windows (in the current workspace) in Activities overview. But I wish to see only the windows that are *not* minimised in the overview.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using a GNOME Shell extension called [**Hide minimized** by danigm](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2639/hide-minimized/) . This extension hides all the minimised windows from the Activities overview.

Refer to this to learn about installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

Comment: That extension does indeed hide the window from Activities overview, but it still keeps the window in the stack to which the shortcut `Switch windows of an app directly` (only windows of the same app, do not confuse with `Switch application`. For instance, if I have 3 windows with Chrome open and I minimize one of them, if I switch between the 3 windows using the keyboard shortcut, the minimized is also shown. Do you know a way to not include it? In that case, I probably want the opposite: don't add it to the alternating windows, but keep on the Activities overiew.